# Is there a way to publish a new report to a workspace with existing reports and an existing dataset?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I use PowerBI Embedded to present several reports to end-users. We have 3 environments and every environment is configured to it's own workspace so: QA envi -> QA workspace, TEST env -> TEST workspace...

My PowerBI setup is made of 2 deployment pipelines, 3 workspaces each - DEV, TEST, and PROD - and each workspace has similar amount of reports. Every dataset has the same name and DirectQuery a table with the same name but the datasets in my QA and TEST workspaces DirectQuery to a QA server while my PROD dataset DirectQuery a PROD server.

The process I take to make changes to a report are download the report .pbix from the qa server, make my changes, publish it, check QA environment, if good promote the report through the deployment pipeline to the TEST workspace, test again, and finally through to the PROD workspace.

If I need to make changes to the table the DirectQuery uses I make my alterations to the table which is created by a StoredProcedure. Run the sp in the qa db, open the dataset in the qa workspace on PBID refresh, validate the new fields are visible format the data if necessary and proceed to publish it back to my QA workspace making sure I'm prompted to 'replace' my existing dataset.

My goal is to publish a new report using the existing dataset in the QA workspace. I thought I could create a report in PBIS from the dataset in the workspace, download the .pbix, make my report and then publish. However, when doing that what actually happened was I'd end up with my new report and a new dataset with identical names and being unable to delete the dataset without deleting my new report.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the report in PBIS, begin by making the report in PBID.

Open PBI Desktop and select 'Get Data'. Select the Dataset from the workspace you want the new report to be in. Create your report and save it then proceed to publish it to your desired workspace.

For some reason this whole process was not clear cut and easy to understand. The documentation does not list this limitation.

Perhaps this limitation is a product of the current design of pipelines, workspaces, and datasets. Have not been using PowerBI for more than 4 months so any advice is welcome.